# How to deploy Contextual Gadget on Google app Marketplace?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I have to deploy my gadget on marketplace... what are the steps of deployment and what are universal navigation link in Marketplace listing.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/preparing

and **Universal Navigation Extension**: this places a menu item for your app in the universal navigation bar, displayed at the top of the page in each Google app. You'll need to include a link URL in the field that appears.

Comment: would u elaborate it. i have a Gmail contextual Gadget than should i give Gmail homePage link to my  Universal Navigation Extension

Comment: its better if you can give your website url,other wise you can give any other link,
if you login with your google apps domain email you will find grid at upper right side corner,you will see list of marketplace apps which you installed for your domain ,when you click on that button it will redirect to the link which you give in the place of Universal Navigation Extension